# Prepend and Append at the same time

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

```
$('.testimonials blockquote p')
.prepend('<span class="quo ldquo">&ldquo;</span>')
.append('<span class="quo rdquo">&rdquo;</span>');
```

...prepends and appends TWICE. How do I prepend ldquo + whatever content inside the p + rdquo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't prepend/append **twice** at this end. When I run it against this test HTML

```
<div class='testimonials'>
<blockquote><p>Testing</p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>One</p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Two</p></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Three</p></blockquote>
</div>
```

...I end up with each paragraph in quotes (just one pair, not two).

Perhaps your CSS is applying the quotes (look at the `quo` and `ldquo`/`rdquot` CSS classes), and then of course you're *also* including them in your markup, and so ending up with two of each.

Comment: Ermm...yes included them in the markup too and forgot. sorry. :P

Comment: @Nimbuz Please accept this answer if it gave you the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your selector matches 2 elements, or you have incorrectly nested p elements.

You could add a `:first`, or try this to see how many it is matching

```
alert($('.testimonials blockquote p').length);
```

or see what they are matching like this

```
$('.testimonials blockquote p').css({ border: '1px solid red' });
```